# Iterate over multiple columns in a csv file and convert them into a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, csv, multiple-columns

Suppose I have a csv file which have 2 columns username, tweet. For each user, how can get all the tweets he made into a list. For example the list should be something like list(c(user1,tweet1,t2,t3),c(u2,t7,t8,t9),....)

```
usernameslist <- alldata$V5
usernameslist <- usernameslist[-1]
tweetslist <- alldata$V2
tweetslist <- tweetslist[-1]

user_and_his_tweets <- split(tweetslist,usernameslist, drop = FALSE )
mylist <- list() 
for(i in 1:length(user_and_his_tweets)){
mylist <- list(mylist,c(names(user_and_his_tweets[i]),as.character(user_and_his_tweets[[i]])))
}
```

This is what I tried. But "mylist" is not in the format I wanted.

Comment: What did you already try to get the wanted results?

Comment: Take a look at `?split`. Without reproducible data, there's not much more I can say.